# elasticsearch tokenizer setting

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to change below states into JAVA.

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/test' -d '
{
    "settings" : {
        "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "my_ngram_analyzer" : {
                    "tokenizer" : "my_ngram_tokenizer"
                }
            },
            "tokenizer" : {
                "my_ngram_tokenizer" : {
                    "type" : "nGram",
                    "min_gram" : "2",
                    "max_gram" : "3",
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

I try to solve this problem as follows:

```
client.admin().indices().prepareCreate("test")
        .setSettings(ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().loadFromSource(jsonBuilder()
            .startObject()
                .startObject("analysis")
                    .startObject("analyzer")
                        .startObject("my_ngram_analyzer")
                            .field("tokenizer", "my_ngram_tokenizer")    
                        .endObject()
                        .startObject("tokenizer")
                            .field("type", "nGram")    
                            .field("min_gram", "2")
                            .field("max_gram","3")
                        .endObject()

                    .endObject()
                .endObject()
            .endObject().string()))
        .execute().actionGet();
```

Unfortunately, I got an error about jsonBuilder()

Please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there anything you have tried using Java? If so, what problems did you run into?

Answer (score 2):

Your `startObject()` / `endObject()` don't seem to correspond to the JSON version you posted.

I think a `endObject()` is missing before the `.startObject("tokenizer")`. I would do something like :

```
client.admin().indices().prepareCreate("test")
    .setSettings(ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder().loadFromSource(jsonBuilder()
        .startObject()
            .startObject("analysis")
                .startObject("analyzer")
                    .startObject("my_ngram_analyzer")
                        .field("tokenizer", "my_ngram_tokenizer")    
                    .endObject()
                .endObject()
                .startObject("tokenizer")
                    .field("type", "nGram")    
                    .field("min_gram", "2")
                    .field("max_gram","3")
                .endObject()
            .endObject()
        .endObject().string()))
    .execute().actionGet();
```

If it doesn't work, give us the full error stack trace. It would be helpful.

Comment: @Soo Could you accept the answer if it was useful please? That's even better that saying thanks ;)